# How do i group by month with other annotated fields?

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
    class Diary(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        gender = models.CharField()
        date = models.DateField()
        happy = models.BooleanField()
```

and in the views, i want to group the Diary by month. and i also want to annotate the diary by feelings, so if happy=False, i want to return it as Sad, if happy=True then i want to return Happy. but if there both happy=False and happy=True in the queryset after i group by date, i want to return the feelings as Sad.

i tried to annotate like this:

```
queryset = Diary.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.values('date')
queryset = queryset.annotate(feelings=Case(When(happy=True, then=Value("Happy"))), default=Value("Sad"))
```

but in the same month, if i have both Sad and Happy feelings, i get two rows like this:

```
{
    "date": "2020-08-20",
    "feelings": "Happy"
},
{
    "date": "2020-08-20",
    "feelings": "Sad"
}
```

is there a way to group it by month and annotate the feelings as Sad if there is at least one queryset that have happy=False? sorry i'm rather new to Django, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure this is the best way but i have found a working solution. I'm going to give my solution here just in case someone else needs it.

I first count the total happy for the diary for each month,

```
queryset = Diary.objects.all()
queryset = queryset.values('date')
queryset = queryset.annotate(
    happy_count=Count(Case(When(happy=True, then=1)))
)
```

and then i annotated for the second time to get the feelings.

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(feelings=Case(When(
    happy_count=Count(Q(happy=True)), then=Value("Happy"),
    default=Value("Sad"), output_field=models.CharField()
)))
```

That's it! If you need this and came across this answer, i hope it works well for you!